# Need help with bit patterns

Tags: electrical-engineering

For a 2-bit machine, there are 4 bit patterns, each bit pattern represents a unique integer value in base 10 according to different methods: unsigned, signed magnitude, 1's complement, 2's complement.

Write down all the possible bit patterns (in increasing order) for a 4-bit machine, and for each bit pattern, write down the unique integer value in base 10 according to unsigned, signed magnitude, 1's complement, 2's complement methods.

My answer:

[image: My answer]

Can anyone please check if this is right?

Comment: This appears to be homework. If so, it would make the most sense by far to approach your instructor, teaching assistant and/or classmates for help checking your work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your answers for the various interpretations are correct for what you have currently. However, you're missing 7 bit patterns. You still need $1001, 1010, 1011,$ etc. In 4-bits, the highest bit pattern should be $1111$, not $1000$. In base 10, this would be like asking for all numbers that can be expressed in 2 digits and then stopping at 10.